# ANDROID Integrate my app with Waze

Tags: java, android, waze

I want to integrate Waze into my android application. I follow the steps from the link below.

https://www.waze.com/about/dev#android_api

I search through the questions and found this same one but it is for ios

[xcode and waze integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688290/xcode-and-waze-integration)

Below is the code which i use.

```
try
            {
                String url = "waze://?q=Hawaii";
                Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url) );
                startActivity( intent );
            }
            catch ( ActivityNotFoundException ex  )
            {
                Intent intent =
                        new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "market://details?id=com.waze" ) );
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Why I got the following error when I run it?

```
Process: com.domain.appname, PID: 5711
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.waze }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change

```
market://details?id=com.waze
```

to

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waze
```

you can also add this validation to avoid crash

`intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null`